# Pattern to Break Inheritance without affecting existing Behavior

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have classes with inherits from other classes. I am looking for pattern which will allow me to break this type of class to class inheritance and use Interface instead.

For example:
Consider I have Base class and few derive classes as follows

```
Lib A :
class Base { ... }


Clients:
class Derived1 : public Base { ... }
class Derived2 : public Base { ... }
class Derived3 : public Derived2 { ... }
```

And clients uses objects of Base, Derived1, Derived2, Derived3.

I want to keep expose Base as interface.
Such that,

```
Lib A will contain:
Interface IBase ( exposed )
and Class BaseImpl ( internal )

And clients will use
class Derived1 : public IBase { .. }
class Derived2 : public IBase { .. }
class Derived3 : public IBase { .. }
```

Now problem is, if I make changes as above, I will loose default implementation provided by BaseImpl here.

1 possible solution that I could think of is having factory as:

```
Lib A:

Interface IBase { ... }
class BaseImpl : public IBase { 
...
}
export static IBase* GetDefaultBase() 
{
   return new Base();
}

clients:

class Derived1 : public IBase
{

public:
 Derived1() { 
m_base = GetDefaultBase();
}

// and all implemented apis can use m_base to call default behavior provided by BaseImpl.
```

I dont see any issues with this approach. But I am curious to know, are there any well known pattern / solutions available for such refactoring problem?

Thanks,
Kailas

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that you lose the ability to create the objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: If you tell us, why you want to break this structure it might be easier to recommend a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Idea is to hide real implemenation behind interface and export less function out side project